# Can you use an interface as type for an ArrayList?

Tags: java

Interface

```
public interface Inter
{
}
```

Is it possible for this to be done because, the objects i am placing inside the ArrayList do not share the same parent class but, they all share the same interface.

Inside my Main method

```
List<Inter> inventory = new ArrayList<Inter>();
```

Comment: Why not try this first before asking this question??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is definitely possible, and it would let you mix different implementations of `Inter` in the same `List`:

```
public class InterImplOne implements Inter {
    ...
}
public class InterImplTwo implements Inter {
    ...
}    ...
List<Inter> inventory = new ArrayList<Inter>();
inventory.add(new InterImplOne());
inventory.add(new InterImplTwo());
```

This is very useful when you want to program to an interface of multiple items which need to have different implementations.

Comment: but while iterating List<Interface> , how do we extract the exact object and how do we know which index is holding what object type in the list

Comment: @prnjn You do this only if you want to treat your objects in a uniform way, i.e. when the exact type does not matter as long as they all conform to the same interface. If you have to figure out the exact type (e.g. by using `instanceof`) then your interface isn't done right.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible. Next time seriously just try this for yourself.

This method is often very useful for exactly what you are trying to do: storing objects that share a common interface

Answer (score 0):

In a word, yes. Look at the documentation for arraylist [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). This works well when you want to have an arraylist that when you iterate over it all objects have similar properties.

As others have said this is a good thing to just try. Experimenting is a good way to learn.

Comment: It's not obvious from your answer. The fact that they are using an ArrayList is irrelevant. It's a matter of generics.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use anonimous inner class to instantiate component of that list like this:

```
package test.regex;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestM {


    interface C{
        public void print(int i ); 
    }

    public TestM() {

        ArrayList<C> list = new ArrayList<TestM.C>();

        for(int i=0; i< 10; i++ ){
            final  int aa = i;
            list.add(new C() {
                public void print(int  a) {
                    System.out.println(Integer.toString(aa + a).toUpperCase()); 
                }
            }); 
        }

        for(C c : list){
            c.print(12); 
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        new TestM(); 
    }

}
```